# How to search (using find command) for directories and copy all the files and directory itself to another directory in linux?

Tags: linux

How to search (using find command) for directories and copy all the files and directory itself to another directory in linux?
Here is what I have so far:

```
find -type d -name "*.ABC" -exec {} /Desktop/NewFile \;
```

I get this as output:

```
find: './GAE/.ABC: PERMISSION DENIED
```

Please Help, Thanks!

Comment: Are you administrator? Do you have permission to access that file?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in as Root and I tried as root and user both.

Comment: "Logged in as root"... You should really use sudo.

Comment: Your find command is not correct...

Answer (score 1):

Your error here above has nothing to do with file **read** permission. You're trying to **execute** the directories you find! Avoid running commands as root or sudo unless: (1) you **really** need it and (2) you **really** know what you're doing. Quite often people asking for root or sudo privileges are exactly the ones should not have it.

That said... there are several ways to copy a directory tree under *nix. This is just one possible approach:

```
$ find <start> -type d -name \*.ABC -exec cp -av {} <target> \;
```

Where:

- `<start>` is a directory name. It's used to tell `find` where to start its search (for example `/usr/local` or `$HOME`)
- `<target>` is another directory name to define the final destination of your copied directories

**UPDATE**

In case you want to search for multiple paths...

```
$ find <start> -type d \( -name \*.ABC -o -name \*.DEF \) -exec cp -av {} <target> \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What should I do if I am looking for more than one file extension.

$ find <start> -type d -name \*.ABC *.DEF -exec cp -av {} <target> \;

Will this work?

Comment: Thanks. Is there way to include variables and create loop in order to search many folders using variables from a text file?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
find ./source_dir -name \*.png -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t path/to/destination
```

For more info, you can look up [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1649040).